# Deleting Dynamic Struct in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have struct named Linked number

```
struct LinkedNum{
    int num;
    LinkedNum * next;
}
```

Then I allocate a dynamic memory for this structure using new operator.

```
LinkedNum * first;
first = new LinkedNum;
first->num = 10;
first->next = nullptr;

LinkedNum * base;
base = first;
base->next = new LinkedNum;
base = base->next;

base->num = 20;
base->next = nullptr;
```

Now how I will free all the memory used by this struct. There are two structures 1 has num = 10 and other has num = 20.
I want to delete all structures so that there will be no memory leak and no dangling pointers.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<LinkedNum> next;` and don't worry further.

Comment: Use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: Draw out the linked list you have on paper, and think about it for a while. And think about where `first` is pointing.

Comment: Don’t program like it’s done in C. Use C++ features like constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so first you want to start deleting memory from the head of your link or struct. You need to create a loop so it works for multiple structs. 
Such as:

```
while( first != nullptr){
     LinkedNum* curr = first;
     first = first -> next;
     delete curr;
}
```

This code makes a temporary value where the first is stored and it goes along the link deleting each element one by one and updating values as well.
Hopefully this helps you!

Comment: `while (curr != nullptr)` => `while (first != nullptr)`